# How to refer to pointer in C from inline assembly when implementing my own mutex

Tags: c, x86, synchronization, mutex, inline-assembly

As an exercise, I'm trying to implement my own mutex library to be used in my forthcoming C programs. I'm advised to use inline assembly for this and thus have produced the following code for x86 (AT&T):

```
#include "mymutex.h"

void init_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex){
        *mutex = 1;
}

void lock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex){
        asm(    "movq $0, %%rax\n\t"    // temp = 0
                "movq $0, %%rbx\n\t"
                "1: xchgq (mutex), %%rax\n\t"
                "cmpq %%rax, %%rbx\n\t"
                "jz 1b\n\t":::"rax","rbx");
}

void unlock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex){
        *mutex = 1;
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to properly address `*mutex` within the `asm()` inside `lock_my_mutex`. `gcc -c mymutex.c -o mymutex.o` compiles fine, but when try to compile my test program, `count-primes.c`, with `gcc -pthread count-primes.c mymutex.o -o count-primes`, I get the following error: `relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol 'mutex' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC`. I have tried recompiling with `-fPIC` (I do not know how that should help), but I still get the same error.

My header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef __mymutex_h
#define __mymutex_h

// Our mutex is very simple so it is either locked
// or unlocked and we don't keep any other information 
typedef long long my_mutex_t;

// Initializes a mutex to be unlocked
void init_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex);

// Tries to grab a lock. The function only
// returns when the current thread holds the lock
void lock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex);

// Unlock the mutex. You don't need to check to see
// if the current thread holds the lock
void unlock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex);

#endif
```

In `count-primes.c`, I try to utilize the mutex like this:

```
my_mutex_t lock;
...

lock_my_mutex(&lock);
                        // Synchronized operation
unlock_my_mutex(&lock);

...
```

I suspect that the problem has to do with my addressing of mutex in the usage of `asm()` and think that understanding how (and why) to do this would enable me to solve the exercise. But help in any other regard is also very much appreciated.

Best,

Steffen.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know AT&T syntax, very well.  However it seems to me you want to dereference `mutex`.  In Intel syntax we would write something like `xchg [mutex], rax`.  hope this helps

Comment: Yes! I see. Thanks. That must be the equivalent of xchg (mutex) in AT&T. I've updated my code accordingly, but still, I'm stuck with the same error.

Comment: `*mutex = 1;` needs to be `volatile` to make sure it's not optimized with dead-store elimination or something, and needs a compiler memory barrier ahead of it, like `asm("" ::: "memory");` (implicitly `volatile` because no output operands).  So `typedef volatile unsigned my_mutex_t;` would be more appropriate.  Or `volatile unsigned char`.  Anyway, if you leave out the memory barrier, the store could be done earlier, before the end of the critical section.

Comment: `long long * lock;` and you pass `&lock` to your functions: You're now modifying a pointer to a pointer, and (unless you init `lock` to point somewhere), you don't have an actual `my_mutex_t` object anywhere, just an uninitialized pointer to one.  Normally you'd declare a mutex by value and pass pointers to it.

Comment: Sorry @PeterCordes. My bad. Fixed it.

Comment: Yup, that fixes the bug, but you should declare it as `my_mutex_t lock`.  Using `long long  lock` hard-codes the `typedef` type, making it harder to change it to a more efficient 32-bit `unsigned` (smaller code size, no need for REX.W prefixes for 64-bit operand-size.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: got'cha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a memory constraint, or an input register containing the address plus a memory clobber:

With memory constraint:

```
void lock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex){
        uint64_t tmp;
        asm(    "mov $0, %1\n\t"
                "1: xchg %1,%0\n\t"
                "test %1, %1\n\t"
                "jz 1b\n\t": "+m(*mutex), "=&r"(tmp));
}
```

With memory clobber:

```
void lock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex){
        uint64_t tmp;
        asm volatile(
                "mov $0, %0\n\t"
                "1: xchg %0,(%1)\n\t"
                "test %0, %0\n\t"
                "jz 1b\n\t": "=&r"(tmp) : "r"(mutex) : "memory");
}
```

Really the memory clobber should be there either way to model the idea that, as a consequence of synchronizing with other threads, the values of other objects may change behind the compiler's back (the ones protected by the mutex). I prefer the latter approach since it doesn't imply that the asm could be removed if the mutex object is never accessed again.

Note that you can further get rid of the mov with:

```
void lock_my_mutex(my_mutex_t *mutex){
        uint64_t tmp;
        asm volatile(
                "1: xchg %0,(%1)\n\t"
                "test %0, %0\n\t"
                "jz 1b\n\t": "=&r"(tmp) : "r"(mutex), "0"(0) : "memory");
}
```

FWIW I would call what you've written a spinlock (a very bad idea), not a mutex.

Comment: It should say `"mov $0, %0\n\t"` and not `"mov $1, %0\n\t"`, right? I've gotten this wrong in my own code as well.

Comment: @SteffenHansen: Why? The goal is to load a 1 to swap into the lock to indicate that the lock is taken.

Comment: "The basic spinlock version of a mutex is a memory location storing 1 for unlocked and 0 for locked" (Operating Systems and Middleware, p. 107). I am by no means pretending to be supercilious – I'm just confused.

Comment: @SteffenHansen: Well you can do it that way if you like, but I consider it completely backwards because the default (zero-initialized) state "should" be unlocked.

Comment: @SteffenHansen: I'll update my answer to match the convention you expected since `jz` is also assuming your convention.

Comment: Asking for the `mutex` address in a register will defeat the compiler's ability to use an addressing mode.  You want to let it substitute `mutex(%rip)` into the template after inlining into a caller that passes the address of a static variable, instead of forcing it to emit a `lea mutex(%rip), %rsi` or something.

Comment: @SteffenHansen: This spinlock is the bare minimum for correctness, but it's pretty horrible.  Even for a spinlock without fallback to OS-assisted sleep/wake, you should normally spin read-only (with `pause`) waiting for the lock to appear available before trying to lock it again, otherwise you can have multiple threads all hammering on the same cache line.  [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](//stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Indeed, there are reasons to prefer a memory operand. If you go that way, I would still include the `"memory"` clobber and the `volatile`.

Comment: @R..: Yes, you need `"memory"` to make it a compiler barrier against reordering, otherwise accesses inside the critical section could move ahead of it at compile time.  With a `"memory"` clobber, `volatile` probably not strictly necessary: it already can't move past any accesses to globals or through pointers that aren't known to be pointing to locals.  And it can't be optimized away unless `++ *mutex` could be optimized away, which it can't be unless escape analysis can prove that no other thread has a reference to it.  But `volatile` doesn't block any useful optimizations, so use it.

Comment: Probably the best option is [a GCC atomic built-in](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), not inline asm at all, like `old = __atomic_exchange_n(&mutex, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL)`, with a C loop around it.  (Or maybe that needs to be `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` ordering, or maybe just `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE`.  On x86 it will be a full barrier for runtime, of course, from `xchg`).

Comment: Guys :-) As mentioned twice in the post, this is an exercise. Therefore, the code is not going to run in some critical system anywhere. At the moment, I'm struggling with learning C, x86 (AT&T), concurrency and synchronization at the same time because I'm taking a university course in Computer architecture, Operating Systems and Networks. Thus for now and for me, it is sufficient to understand the principles. For instance, our curriculum mentions nothing about this clobber-thingy.